# \widehat in text mode in Plain (Xe)TeX?

Tags: xetex, plain-tex, accents

Is there a way to emulate the behaviour of `\widehat` in text mode in Plain (Xe)TeX?  That is, take a single accent<sup>1</sup> and “stretch” it over two or more letters.  I need it in text mode, because it's not for a mathematical formula.

I tried doing the same thing that `\t` does, but that didn't work, because (as I realized in the process) the tie-after is a character of its own, and it doesn't really stretch.

<sup>1</sup> a circumflex for my current task, but I would be thankful to know if there is a more general mechanism.

Comment: The simplest would be `\def\twidehat#1{$\widehat{\hbox{#1}}$}` (you lose kerning information, but this always happens also with `\accent`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\widehat`. This would work without problems with upright fonts, but some tweaking based on the font slant should be needed for slanted ones.

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\twidehat#1{$\m@th\widehat{\hbox{#1}}$}
\catcode`@=12

A\twidehat{c}cent

A\twidehat{cc}ent

A\twidehat{cce}nt

A\twidehat{ccen}t

{\it A\twidehat{cc}ent}

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Depending on the purpose of the macro, it could make sense to `\smash` it or at least do something in order not to create uneven line spacing.